# How to search specific column name ( not A ,B etc) such as Name ,Marks in excel using python and openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

" I have to input the file path ,file name of excel and have to input a specific column name to search whether the column(not A,B etc )(like Name etc) exist or not in excel.If exist i have to give another input of a value to search whether the value exist.

I work with python and loaded the excel sheet using `openpyxl` module.I got directory and file path and kept active excel .I have to iterate the column name to check with search string column name.

```
python
from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
import sys
#give the directory
print("Give filepath :")
filepath = input()
if os.path.exists(filepath):
print("Give file name:")
else:
    print('filepath unbound')
    sys.exit()
filename = input()
df = filepath+"/"+filename
if os.path.isfile(df):
     wb = Workbook()
     wb.save(df)
     sheet = wb.active
else:
   print("file not found")
print("Give search column:")
#giving search string(column name) to check
sc=input()
```

I expected the loop iteration or any method to search the column name of given input

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to search the active sheet and assuming you know the row in which the column header is (`header row`),

```
import openpyxl
import os
import sys

valid_heading_flag = False
#give the directory
print("Give filepath :")
filepath = input()
if os.path.exists(filepath):
    print("Give file name:")
    filename = input()
    df = filepath+"/"+filename
    if os.path.isfile(df):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(df)
        sheet = wb.active
        header_row = 2  # assuming 1st row as the header row
        header_row_data = sheet[header_row]
        #giving search string(column name) to check
        print("Give search column:")
        sc=input()
        for col_index,cell in enumerate(header_row_data):
            if cell.value == sc:
                print('Valid heading at row:{},col:{}'.format(header_row, col_index))
                valid_heading_flag = True
                break
        if not valid_heading_flag:
            print('Not a valid heading')
    else:
        print("file not found")
        sys.exit()
else:
    print('filepath unbound')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks you .But i Face eror like this 
      raise IndexError("{0} is not a valid coordinate or range".format(key))
       IndexError: 0 is not a valid coordinate or range

Comment: @princeantony- corrected code, `head_row` should contain an integer which represent the `excel sheet row number`